# Using Checkboxes in angular material to filter data from a database . Error nameValue.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use checkboxes filter to filter data on a table in material. I have done everything right with no errors on my terminal and on the console. But the moment I tick a checkbox on the browser, this error "nameValue.toLowerCase is not a function" appears on the console.

The lines of codes below identifies the part of the ts file where the error is

filterOptions(positionValue: string[], nameValue: string): ITransactionDetail[] { if ((!positionValue || positionValue.length === 0) && !nameValue) { return this.data; } const filtered = this.data.filter(periodicElement => { return ( (nameValue ? periodicElement.transactionType.toLowerCase().includes(nameValue.toLowerCase()) : false) || (positionValue ? positionValue.includes(periodicElement.id + '') : false) ); }); return filtered; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
nameValue.toString().toLowerCase();
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it still doesn't filter the table

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is occurring cause the nameValue passed to the function is not a string though it's parameter is written as a string..

```
filterOptions(positionValue: string[], nameValue: string)
```

I am assuming you are calling this function in your html file and the value passed through this function is not a string.

To resolve this error make sure that the value passing through is a string or change the function to:

```
nameValue.toString().toLowerCase()
```

Hope this works..

Comment: Thanks, I applied your logic, when I tick the box, there's no error on the console, but it still doesn't filter the table .

Comment: If possible can u replicate your code on stackblitz, so it would be easier to check what's happening..

Comment: I wished it were possible, it is a jhipster library and a company's project . I would put up more of the codes so you can have a wider range of ideas.